# Angalar ui-view dont insert template in

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

**PollRoutes.coffee**

```
  $stateProvider.state 'polls.new',
    url: '/new'
    views:
      "":
        templateUrl: 'polls/form.html'
        controller: 'PollController'
      "page_title":
        template: "<h1 class='page-header'>Create a new poll</h1>"
    resolve:
      auth: ["Auth", (Auth)-> Auth.currentUser()]

  $stateProvider.state 'polls.edit',
    url: '/:id/edit'
    views:
      "":
        templateUrl: 'polls/form.html'
        controller: 'PollController'
      "page_title":
        template: "<h1 class='page-header'>Edit poll \"{{poll.title}}\"</h1>"
    resolve:
      auth: ["Auth", (Auth)-> Auth.currentUser()]
```

insert in **polls/form.html.slim**

```
div ng-view='page_title'
```

I tried various view formats: "page_title", "page_title@", "page_title@polls.edit" and none of them work

[Application link](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/poller/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/templates/polls/form.html.slim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$state` should be like this.

```
$stateProvider
         .state('polls', {
             url: '/',
             data: {pageTitle: 'Edit poll.'},
             resolve: {//here your functions},
             views: {
                 'navbar': {
                     templateUrl: null, //here your template
                     controller: null //here your controller
                 },
                 'body': {
                     templateUrl: "polls/form.html",
                     controller: 'PollController'
                  }
             }});
```

and your views like this,

```
<div ng-view='navbar'></div>

<div ng-view='body'></div>
```

and your tittle can be loaded like this,

```
<title ng-bind="title">My tittle</title>
```

Comment: Thanks, that much nicer, I'll use this immediately, but do you know why my example doesn't work? why `page_title` doesn' insert?

Comment: in your code a didn't se `{  }` that limit where begin the views or your configuration, also you put `$providerState` two times, it's a little mess, you can see your console what error is throwing?

Comment: Its coffeescript and its compiles in [this](http://pastebin.com/XQk0BAxk), no error in console

Comment: oh i didn't knew about it. it seems right. but the two providers may be throwing the errors

Comment: no, I check, I change routes to one $stateProvider as you propose and nothing changed

Comment: seeing in your paste.bin you're returning the $stateProvider, it's suppose to be only a variable of configuration, i don't see the necessity of returning it

Comment: its coffescrept default behavior and it does not affect on issue, also I create a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DkUut5tgfUgrMCW6bBKg?p=preview) representing the issue

Comment: ohh i see what's the problem in your index you should put the  `ui-view` with page_tittle and the empty one, you just put one without nothing and inside your views the other ones, so never reach to the corresponding views

Comment: try this in your index of plunkr `<div ui-view=""></div>
  <div ui-view="page_title"></div>`

Comment: I change my routes to [this](http://pastebin.com/AqLZ3VCa) but I still can't use {{poll.title}} in page-header (line 25) because they have different scopes, I must use "resolve".  Is there other ways?

Comment: I dont want to use resolve because it's mean  move poll retrieving to routes

Comment: uhm you can inject the controller in the page_title view or instead resolve, you can use data, to bind the header